# How to replace gnome-screenshot with flameshot on ubuntu budgie 20.04?

Tags: screenshot, budgie

I tried some tutorials from the internet like "going to keyboard and creating a new shortcut for the print button"- and first that worked. I deleted the default shortcut for "print" and used this button for flameshot (the command: /usr/bin/flameshot gui)

But after restarting the pc, the pc was still using the default gnome-screenshot tool if I pressed "print".

After that, I deleted gnome-screenshot and created the flameshot shortcut from the beginning- then it worked. but- restarting the pc and .... now nothing happend if I pressed "print". Huh ... But I found a solution

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile I coulnd't even use the print button for creating a new shortcut ...
As someone mentioned somewhere in the internet, I installed dconf-editor with

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

and then I searched for screenshot. There was an entry "take-full-screenshot" with ['Print']. I was kinda afraid of leaving this entry blank, because I wasn't sure if this could work, so I changed it to a shortcut, that I would never use:

```
['<Ctrl><Alt>Print']
```

(Switch of the button for using default values so you can modify the value/entry)

Then I could use the print button again and I created the custom shortcut for flameshot again from the beginning and now it works, even after a restart of the computer.

Comment: I have tried to follow these instructions without success, where do I look for "take-full.screenshot" ? "I was able to create a shortcut from the beginning" doing what steps ?

Comment: To create a custom shortcut for Flameshot go to Settings - Keyboard - View and Customize Shortcuts - Custom Shortcuts and set the command to `flameshot gui -c`.